# Recipient Data Personalisation Strings

Tags: marketing-cloud

I'd like to know when/how the following personalisation strings would be used:

- `%%fullname_%%` or `%%fullname%%`
- `%%comment_%%` or `%%comment%%`

They appear in [the documentation](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/personalization_strings/strings/) but there doesn't appear to be a matching profile attribute for these values, which begs the question, why are they documented? Oddly enough, the description for the comment string reads:

> Value of the User Defined profile attribute for this subscriber

So, does that mean that you have to create a user defined profile attribute? I note that you can't create a profile attribute with the name 'FullName' or 'comment' (as I assume they are reserved).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is from some default Profile Attributes inside older versions of SFMC (mostly on the E1.0 instance) that came with [3 default properties](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/profile_and_preference_attributes/).

1. Email Address
2. Full Name
3. UserDefined

> **By default, every account has three profile attributes: Full Name, Email, and UserDefined**, which is intended as a generic attribute that you can use as needed. You cannot modify these attributes.

The ones that are referenced in your question are Full Name and UserDefined, both which appear to have been sunsetted on the newer versions as very few (if anyone) actually used these default attributes.

For the newer versions, I am not sure what exactly you would get if you tried to output either of those personalization strings (I am guessing it would be blank?) nor do I know if you create a 'Full Name' or 'User Defined' attribute, if it would fill in for those strings or not. My guess is it would not.